# What is the reason for the error on running grep.exe (Unix version compiled for Windows) from a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, grep

I tried to run `grep.exe` (Unix version compiled for Windows) from a batch script and got this error:

```
      0 [main] grep 7760 C:\grep.exe: *** fatal error - add_item ("\??", "/", ...) failed, errno 22
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFABB6  0018007215E (00180267E4A, 00180218E59, 00600010000, 000FFFF8B30)
000FFFFABB6  00180046E52 (000FFFF9B98, 000FFFFABB6, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFABB6  00180046E92 (000FFFF9BB0, 00000000016, 00600010000, 000003F3F5C)
000FFFFABB6  001800DEEFD (000FFFFCBB0, 000FFFFCE00, 001800CF158, 00000000000)
000FFFFCC00  00180128545 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFCCC0  001800474B5 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  001800460AC (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  00180046144 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
```

This above error message is shown after running the following line in the batch script:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`reg query "hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\session manager\environment" /v Path ^| %~dp0grep -i directory_being_searched_for `) do set pathExists=true
```

This line of code might look complicated at first, but the `grep` command near the end is what's being executed eventually, which fails at some point.

What seems to be causing this failure?

If there's no easy solution, I don't mind workarounds.

Comment: `for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (\`reg query "%KeyName%" /v Path\`) do for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ( \`echo ";%%c"^| find /i ";%subPath%"\`) do set "pathExists=true  [%subPath%]"` should work although might give false positives e.g. for invalid subpath like `set "subPath=c:\program fi"`

Comment: @Mofi You're right about the complexity of the question. I thought the context of the call might've been relevant since I've never faced an issue with grep.exe when using it directly in command line.

Comment: @Mofi You might be right about directory_being_searched_for (it is Foo.Bar in my case). The dot might be causing the issue. You might want to post that as an answer. If I verify that your hint works, I'll vote it as the best answer and that'll earn you some easy points :)

Comment: @Mofi On the other hand, if your hint doesn't work, I'll use find or findstr, again, like you suggested. Regardless, thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%~dp0grep` should be enclosed in double quotes in case of path to `grep.exe` (= batch file path) contains a space or another syntax critical character from this list `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` output by command interpreter itself on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` on last page.

And the file extension `.exe` should be also appended to avoid the need to search for an executable by Windows command interpreter in batch file directory.

But the main problem causing the fatal error is most likely the string replaced in question by

```
directory_being_searched_for
```

1. Is the string enclosed in double quotes?
2. Does it contain regular expression characters like `?` or `*` or `.`?
3. And is the directory with path and contains therefore also 1 or more backslashes?

**grep** is ported from Unix to Windows. Therefore **grep** interprets a backslash as an escape character like C/C++/C#/JavaScript and many other programming and scripting languages and not as directory separator like Windows.

I don't have installed **grep** (which version downloaded from where?) and therefore can't reproduce this issue and find out the reason for the fatal error.

But perhaps the solution is using **grep** option `-F` to let **grep** interpret the search string pattern as fixed string instead of regular expression.

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path ^| "%~dp0grep.exe" -i -F "directory_being_searched_for"`) do set "pathExists=true"
```

But there are easier solutions as Windows has the console applications **find** and **findstr**  for simple fixed string searches and simple regular expression searches.

Example with **find**:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe" "directory_being_searched_for"`) do echo set "pathExists=true"
```

Operator `|` redirects the output of **reg** to handle *STDOUT* to the input handle *STDIN* of **find**. `|` must be escaped here with `^` to avoid being interpreted for command **for** which would result in an exit of batch processing because of a syntax error. Please see Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for more details.

But this simple command line does not verify if the complete directory path is really included in environment variable **PATH** as defined in Windows registry. A better verification would be for example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PathExists=false"
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path') do (
    if /I "%%A"=="Path" (
        set "SystemPath=;%%C;"
        set "SystemPath=!SystemPath:"=!"
        if not "!SystemPath:;directory_being_searched_for;=!" == "!SystemPath!" set "PathExists=true"
    )
)
echo Path exists: %PathExists%
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`